# If statement to copy cells if they are NOT blank else, don't copy

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I just wanna ask how should I write an if statement that would copy and paste the data on a range of cells IF they are NOT empty, and if that certain range of cells are empty, then it should not copy anything.

Any suggestion are very appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Use the macro recorder to find out about copying and pasting, then wrap that code into a `For Each` loop for all cells that you want to check and for each of them, check whether or not their value is empty: `If Range.Value = "" Then...`

Comment: Is this not similar to your previous thread?

Comment: I got the copying and pasting thing covered, just didnt know the syntax to use for the if statement. Anyway, the approach i need to do is use a loop to check each and every cell if thry are empty or not right?

Comment: @davesexcel no, what i was asking there was pasting to the next empty row, this one is copying the not empty rangenof cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This copies cell values from column 1 (UsedRange) to column 2 if the cell is not empty:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub copyIfNotEmpty()

    Dim cel As Range, lRow As Long

    'next line determines the last row in column 1 (A), of the first Worksheet
    lRow = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(1).Rows.Count

    'iterate over every cell in the UsedRange of column A
    For Each cel In Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A" & lRow)

        'cel represents the current cell
        'being processed in this iteration of the loop

        'Len() determines number of characters in the cell
        If Len(cel.Value2) > 0 Then

            'if cel is not empty, copy the value to the cell next to it

            'cel.Offset(0, 1): cell that is offset from current cell
            ' - 0 rows from current cell's row (1 would be row below, -1 row above)
            ' - 1 column to the right of current cell's column (-1 is column to its left)

            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = cel.Value2

        End If

    Next    'move on the next (lower) cell in column 1

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't want to sound stupid or anything, but im kinda new in vba, and uhm if you can explain what this code does, that would be awesome

Comment: Thanks mate! Appreciate it the effort

Answer (score 0):

See the example video here,I supplied 2 examples, a loop and a filter.
https://youtu.be/a8QJ9BAHlhE

[sample workbook.](http://nebula.wsimg.com/10143c108e2a63909e799c24c11c6855?AccessKeyId=21C1C50B7677872F602F&disposition=0&alloworigin=1)

```
Sub LoopExample()
    Dim Rws As Long, rng As Range, c As Range

    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(Rws, "A"))

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c <> "" Then
            c.Copy Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
Sub FilterExample()
    Dim Rws As Long, rng As Range

    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Columns("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Set rng = Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(Rws, "A"))
    rng.Copy Range("D2")
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = 0
End Sub
```